# Inserting an element directly after another element with xmlstarlet doesn't works

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I know questions like these have been answered many times, but none of them work for me, at least... with my XML file. I tried those answers with simpler XML trees and they worked, nevertheless, with mine they don't. That's why I'm posting a question hoping for someone to enlighten me :-)

My XML (Liferay stuff) is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans>
    <bean id="liferayDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetSource" ref="shardDataSourceTargetSource" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="liferayHibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetSource" ref="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="shardDataSource0" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
                <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.default." />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shardDataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
                <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.NIGERIA." />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shardDataSource2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
                <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.MEDLAHO." />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="shardDataSourceTargetSource" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.ShardDataSourceTargetSource">    
        <property name="dataSources">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>default</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="shardDataSource0" />
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>NIGERIA</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="shardDataSource1" />
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>MEDLAHO</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="shardDataSource2" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.ShardSessionFactoryTargetSource">
        <property name="shardDataSourceTargetSource" ref="shardDataSourceTargetSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc.MappingSqlQueryFactoryUtil" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc.MappingSqlQueryFactoryUtil">
        <property name="mappingSqlQueryFactory">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.ShardMappingSqlQueryFactoryImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc.SqlUpdateFactoryUtil" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc.SqlUpdateFactoryUtil">
        <property name="sqlUpdateFactory">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.ShardSqlUpdateFactoryImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.shard.ShardUtil" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.shard.ShardUtil">
        <property name="shard">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.ShardImpl">
                <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InfrastructureUtil" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InfrastructureUtil">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="liferayDataSource" />
        <property name="mailSession" ref="mailSession" />
        <property name="shardDataSourceTargetSource" ref="shardDataSourceTargetSource" />
        <property name="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource" ref="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="liferayTransactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice">
        <property name="shardDataSourceTargetSource" ref="shardDataSourceTargetSource" />
        <property name="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource" ref="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardCompanyAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardCompanyAdvice">
        <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPortletAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPortletAdvice">
        <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice">
        <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice">
        <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardIterativelyAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardIterativelyAdvice">
        <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardParameterAdvice" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardParameterAdvice">
        <property name="shardAdvice" ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="false">
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardCompanyAdvice" pointcut="bean(com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalService)" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" pointcut="execution(void com.liferay.portal.convert.messaging.ConvertProcessMessageListener.receive(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" pointcut="execution(void com.liferay.portal.events.StartupHelper.updateIndexes())" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" pointcut="execution(void com.liferay.portal.events.StartupHelper.upgradeProcess(int))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalService.getBuildNumberOrCreate())" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" pointcut="execution(void com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceComponentLocalService.upgradeDB(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardGloballyAdvice" pointcut="execution(void com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService.checkArticles())" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardIterativelyAdvice" pointcut="execution(void com.liferay.portal.events.StartupHelper.verifyProcess(boolean, boolean))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardParameterAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.liferay.portal.service.AccountLocalService.getAccount(long, long))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardParameterAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService.getCompanyGroup(long))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardParameterAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService.searchCount(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice" pointcut="bean(*Persistence) || bean(*Finder)" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPortletAdvice" pointcut="bean(com.liferay.portal.service.PortletLocalService)" />
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

What I'd like, is to have another **bean** like block, for example:

```
    <bean id="shardDataSource4" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
                <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.default." />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Just after the one with **id=shardDataSource0**

I haven't tried to insert the full block with all the child elements and their attributes, I'm just trying to insert a new **bean** element for a start... but I cannot.

I've tried many options, but it cannot get as simply as this one:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -a /beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource0'] -t elem -n bean -v "" file.xml
```

Which doesn't works :-( it just does nothing, the file is not modified and the exit code is 0.

So... what am I missing here guys???

Many, many thanks in advance.

Note: I'm running SLES Expanded Support platform release 6.7, and the xmlstarlet package is: xmlstarlet-1.5.0-1.el6.rf.x86_64

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer of @npostavs, I managed to append the whole **bean** block. The correct line is the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed -a "/beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource0']" -t elem -n beanTMP -v ""  \
    -i //beanTMP -t attr -n "id" -v "shardDataSource1" \
    -i //beanTMP -t attr -n "class" -v "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy" \
    -s //beanTMP -t elem -n "propertyTMP" -v "" \
    -i //propertyTMP -t attr -n "name" -v "targetDataSource" \
    -s //propertyTMP -t elem -n "beanTMP2" -v "" \
    -i //beanTMP2 -t attr -n "class" -v "com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean" \
    -s //beanTMP2 -t elem -n "propertyTMP2" -i //propertyTMP2 -t attr -n "name" -v "propertyPrefix" \
    -i //propertyTMP2 -t attr -n "value" -v "jdbc.default." \
    -r //propertyTMP -v "property" \
    -r //propertyTMP2 -v "property" \
    -r //beanTMP -v "bean" \
    -r //beanTMP2 -v "bean" \
    file.xml
```

Nevertheless, the result is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans>
  <bean id="shardDataSource0" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
      <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
        <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.default."/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="shardDataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy"><property name="targetDataSource"><bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean"><property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.default."/></bean></property></bean>
</beans>
```

That means I'm not getting a proper formatting. I tried the global options -P -S and --ps or --pf but none of them works.... 
Could anybody have an idea of why this happens?

Many thanks to all in advance!!

---

**UPDATE 2**

I've managed to get a proper formatting piping the first xmlstarlet line to: **xmlstarlet fo -R** which formats the whole document. But I'm sure this is not the way to go...so guys,.. any clues?

Comment: XML namespace issue.

Comment: Actually, I posted the file with all the attributes for the **bean** element, but for testing, I removed them all. I'm gonna update the OP.

Comment: You need an extra set of quotes: `"/beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource0']"`

Comment: @npostavs, thank you a lot for your answer, this was indeed, the missing thing for this command to work. Now I have the following line for creating the whole **bean** block. Nevertheless, I'm not having a proper fomattting, (even with the addition of -P -S global options) I'm updating the OP. Thank again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

------------ INPUT------------

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans>
  <bean id="liferayHibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSource" ref="shardSessionFactoryTargetSource"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="shardDataSource0" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
      <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
        <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.default."/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="shardDataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
      <bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean">
        <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.NIGERIA."/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

------------ 1------------

```
xml ed
-a beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource0'] -t elem -n bean
-i beans/bean[not(@*)] -t attr -n id -v shardDataSource4
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4'] -t attr -n class -v org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy
-s beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4'] -t elem -n property
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property -t attr -n name -v targetDataSource
-s beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property -t elem -n bean
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean -t attr -n class -v com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean
-s beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean -t elem -n property
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean/property -t attr -n name -v propertyPrefix
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean/property -t attr -n value -v jdbc.default. file.xml
```

------------ 2------------

```
xml ed
-a beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource0'] -t elem -n xxx
-i //xxx -t attr -n id -v shardDataSource4
-i //xxx -t attr -n class -v org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy
-s //xxx -t elem -n property
-i //xxx/property -t attr -n name -v targetDataSource
-s //xxx/property -t elem -n bean
-i //xxx/property/bean -t attr -n class -v com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean
-s //xxx/property/bean -t elem -n property
-i //xxx/property/bean/property -t attr -n name -v propertyPrefix
-i //xxx/property/bean/property -t attr -n value -v jdbc.default.
-r //xxx -v bean file.xml
```

------------ 3------------

```
xml ed
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource1'] -t elem -n bean
-i beans/bean[not(@*)] -t attr -n id -v shardDataSource4
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4'] -t attr -n class -v org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy
-s beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4'] -t elem -n property
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property -t attr -n name -v targetDataSource
-s beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property -t elem -n bean
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean -t attr -n class -v com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean
-s beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean -t elem -n property
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean/property -t attr -n name -v propertyPrefix
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']/property/bean/property -t attr -n value -v jdbc.default. file.xml
```

------------ 4------------

```
xml ed -a beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource0'] -t elem -n bean
-i beans/bean[not(@*)] -t attr -n id -v shardDataSource4
-i beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4'] -t attr -n class -v org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy
-u beans/bean[@id='shardDataSource4']
-v "<property name=\"targetDataSource\"><bean class=\"com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean\"><property name=\"propertyPrefix\" value=\"jdbc.default.\" /></bean></property>" file.xml | xml unesc | xml fo
```